# Storing images in a Sql Server 2008 database using Filegroups/Filestreams

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, filestream, filegroup

Has anyone had an experience storing user uploaded images in a MSSQL 2008 Database using Filegroups and Filestreams? I read a few articles that seemed to say they are a good idea because you get all the advantages of storing images on disk and in the db. For example

I have implemented this for my current project but it seems like I'm doing a lot of unnecessary work having to convert the bytes and writing them as an image.
(I'm using ASP.Net MVC)

Are there any other gotchas I should be worrying about? Should I really being storing these images on the disk myself instead? Should I look into other alternatives such as Amazon AWS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Azure Blog Storage. It works great for image storage!

Answer (score 0):

I've written a couple of apps with MVC now both of which require images stored and I've placed them in a database as that way it was easier to associate images to records rather than have a record giving me the file name and location.

The thing I also do is I reduce the size of the image if it's too big.  No point storing a 4mg file if a smaller one will fit in place just as well.